# C# HttpClient POST JSON Return Code = OK (200), but nothing happens

Tags: c#

Trying to update my JSON file, I get the return code 'OK' (200), but the file doesn't change. The JSON string contains the updated entry.

What do I wrong?

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

            RootObject root = null;
            HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost/fruits.json",
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                HttpContent HttpContent = HttpResponseMessage.Content;
                string MyContent = await HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(MyContent);
                ReturnContentModels = new AsyncObservableCollection<ContentModel>(root.products);
                Debugger.Break();
            }

            ContentModel contentModel = ReturnContentModels[0];
            contentModel.Name = "Apfelsinen";
            List<ContentModel> products1 = new List<ContentModel>(ReturnContentModels);

            RootObject root1 = new RootObject
            {
                meta = root.meta,
                products = products1
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root1, Formatting.Indented);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost/fruits.json", stringContent);
            Debugger.Break();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you are currently getting the record from a JSON file directly and modifying it. You cannot directly modify a file using httpClient. You need a server (back-end application) of some kind to understand your POST request.

You can use [JSON-Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to serve your JSONfile and make GET, POST and other requests to it.

Comment: What I originally wanted to do is to store the JSON file on my webspace to be edited from my c# WPF app. Is that possible at all? I hope this question isn't too much stupid...